# slippry slider image slides displaying at once on page load

Tags: jquery, css, slider, carousel

I'm using slippry slider for my carousel and the issue I have is that all the slides display in a list, then on page load then after about a second the slider fixes itsef as if the CSS has just loaded and the slider is working as it should be. So how do i stop all the slides flashing up at once for that one second?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the HTML after the slider is loaded and working, you'll notice that Slippry adds "opacity: 0: as a inline style to the slide elements (`<li></li>`). As it does it's magic, it simply turns the 0 into a 1 for the slide currently being displayed.

To work around this, (this may not be the best way) I have added made the opacity of the slides 0 via CSS, so nothing is displayed until Slippry is loaded. Slippry then adds the 1 for the active slide.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by initially having the list element hidden, then displayed once Slippry fires the onSliderLoad callback event.